# Use powershell to run a command for changed files in git

Tags: powershell

I want to use `jb cleanupcode --include .\file1;.\file2` to only format code that has changed.
I.e. I want to run `git diff --name-only` and then feed the output to the `jb cleanupcode` command using its `--include` flag.

The issue is that `git diff --name-only` produces a list of files one-per-line.

*Question*: how do I take a stream of path-per-file and turn it into a semicolon-separated list fed to a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-join` operator to join the resulting paths together:

```
$names = @(git diff --name-only) -join ';'
jb cleanupcode --include $names
```

Or as a single statement:

```
jb cleanupcode --include (@(git diff --name-only) -join ';')
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make it a one-liner using pipes?

Comment: @THX-1138 piping data makes little sense since you need to pass all names to `jb` up front - but I've updated the answer to show how you can combine the statements